# Operation Must use an updatable query-Access Sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to update data from OrderDetails table to Ordert table. Code:-

```
UPDATE  OrderDetails
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Product_ID, 
                  Sum(Ordert.Carton_Count) AS Carton_Count, 
                  Sum(Ordert.Total_Product) AS Total_Product, 
                Sum(Ordert.Total_Price) AS Total_Price
FROM Ordert
GROUP BY Product_ID) Ordert
ON OrderDetails.Product_ID = Ordert.Product_ID
SET  OrderDetails.Cartons = Ordert.Carton_Count,
OrderDetails.Total_Product = Ordert.Total_Product,
OrderDetails.Total_Price = Ordert.Total_Price
```

When I run the query it shows an error saying "Operation Must be use an updatable query"

Comment: You can't combine GROUP BY with an UPDATE query. See https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: See https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html for a discussion and some unsatisfying workarounds.

Comment: If your underlying data base is ACE, then only the workarounds described above can be used.  If by some chance your tables are mapped into Access from some other database, then you can also use a MERGE SQL statement as a pass-through query where you code the MERGE statement using the syntax of your underlying data base.

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed.